# Why x-y=4 is creating a plane in 3D space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra, I don't understand why x-y = 4 is creating a plane in 3d space, since the value of z is always zero, then x - y = 4 should create line only right?

[Image taken using GeoGebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH5Mi.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The value of z is always zero" - that is not correct. The equation $x-y=4$ *places no constraints on* $z$; therefore, $z$ can be anything, not necessarily zero. So it is a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have got another doubt, In a system of linear equations, does the zero constraints implicitly applied? I am taking three equations, **x - y = 4, 2y + z = 6 and z = 2**, these three planes will intersect at a particular point, it's like three lines are intersecting at a particular point, so zero constraints implicitly applied? @Ted